# CWE Top 25 defects coverty scan

Tags: coverity

Coverty Scan Dashboard shows me some "CWE Top 25 defects". Is there any way to find which ones exactly are these in the Scan result view?

Answer (score 0):

After some further searching, it turned out to be actually quite easy. In the defect viewer, you can click on the gear symbol in the top bar. This permits to set filters and there is a specific filter option where you can fill in the CWE.